# c (arduino) misc function returning char pointer

Tags: c++, string, arduino

i found function in some code. Looks like that function generates some random number with variable length and returns char*

```
char* result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) 
{
  result[i] = 48 + random(9);
}
result[length] = '\0';
```

When i tested it, i was surprised that this code works
But in theory char* is read only data, so this accessing to the elements should be incorrect.
Could someone explain it to me?

I think it will be better that the creator will use char array and then copy that memory to the char*
(i do not have link to code)

Comment: "char* is read only data". No it's not necessarily so and certainly not in the example you have given. Perhaps you are thinking about code like `char *result = "a constant string";`.

Comment: arduino is not `C`. It is C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your code does not work. You write outside the array in this line

```
result[length] = '\0';
```

the code shuold look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) 
{
  result[i] = 48 + random(9);
}
result[length - 1] = '\0';
```

char is just an integer type and it can be read or written.

if you want make it not writable (at least from the C++ point of view) you need to declare it as `const`.

```
const char a;
const char *ptr1;
char * const ptr2;
const char * const ptr3;
```

where:

`ptr1` is a pointer to const char

`ptr2` is a const pointer to char

`ptr2` is a const pointer to const char

Comment: Well, it is not my code, i found it in one example, Thank you for explaining.

Comment: do not trust author of this example anymore.